# How do I overclock Intel Integrated Graphics Q965/Q963 controlller in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, intel-graphics, intel-gma

Here is the outpt of the command "lshw -c video" , which I ran as an Superuser

```
product: 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
```

Comment: Are you sure your gpu supports overclocking? https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006728/graphics.html

Comment: Yes I want to overclock it

Comment: IS there any way to overclock it sir

Comment: There  must be some way to overclock it on Ubuntu

Comment: Then ask the Ubuntu developers at Canonical: https://ubuntu.com/support

Comment: Sir do you have any tool which will enable  me to do overclocking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intel graphics drivers for Linux do not support overclocking. Also, given your GPU age, even successful overclocking won't give you much - it's extremely weak and slow. Normally onboard graphics starts to work considerably faster when your RAM runs in dual channel mode, so if I were you, I'd add an extra RAM module instead.

Comment: Sir I don't have any other ram stick

Comment: Then buy one. Dual channel RAM is a must for integrated graphics: https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/3244-amd-r5-2400g-memory-kit-benchmarks-and-single-vs-dual-channel https://nucblog.net/2015/09/dual-channel-vs-single-channel-does-it-matter/

Comment: Leave it sir anyways I will be planing to an GPU update in the future..Thanks for answering sir..I appreciate your help